# Proving that $(A/I)\otimes M\simeq M/IM$ via the exact sequence $0\to I\to A\to A/I \to 0$

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

I was trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $I$ an ideal and $M$ an $A$-module. Prove that $$(A/I)\otimes M\simeq M/IM$$

I was able to do this directly by constructing a map from the tensor product to the quotient using the universal property for tensor products, but underneath the exercise, the author of the book gives the following tip:

> Tensor the exact sequence $$0\to I\to A\to A/I \to 0$$ with $M$.

and I don't get how this is useful. If we tensor this exact sequence, we get: $$I\otimes M \to A\otimes M \to (A/I)\otimes M \to 0$$

And I don't see how this is relevant to the exercise.

Why can this $(A/I)\otimes M\simeq M/IM$ be proved by analyzing this exact sequence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a natural isomorphism $A\otimes_A M\cong M$ which maps $a\otimes m\to am$. It's easy to check that the image of the map $I\otimes_A M\to A\otimes_A M$ is mapped under this isomorphism precisely to the submodule $IM\subseteq M$. So the exact sequence induces a surjective map $M\to (A/I)\otimes_A M$, and its kernel is $IM$. Now the result follows from the isomorphism theorems.